# How to get Angular component to take full height of screen

Tags: javascript, css, angular, user-interface, frontend

I'm nesting an angular component inside another one that is taking up the whole screen using `height:100%;` in the component's css file.  I'm attempting to layer them and want each component to take up the whole screen height, but `height:100%` has no effect.

For reference I'm attempting to emulate something like http://andrewborstein.github.io/portfolio/

Comment: you have crated awesome site. which technologies did you use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add style to your element:

```
height: 100vh;
```

Or create a css class and add it to element:

```
.full-height {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

use `:host` selector

hello.component.css

```
:host{
    background: #4285f4;
    color:#fff;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 100  
}
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-full-screen)