# Angular: Show Only the Component and Hide Header and Footer

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

How do I only show the Angular Component on a page, and hide everything else including the header and footer from the angular component? The header and footer are automatically placed in all our components, we don't even code for them in html.

[Component Picture in Green Border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsvuc.png)

Using the following solution partially works, however sometimes the header and footer still show up few seconds, while the real component is loading.

```
:host{
  background: #4285f4;
  color:#fff;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

[How to get Angular component to take full height of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332847/how-to-get-angular-component-to-take-full-height-of-screen)

This is the Product Component html:

```
<div class="whole-container">
  <div class="product-data">
    <div>{{product?.productNumber}}</div>
    <div>{{product?.productName}}</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Paste your component code so someone can suggest to better

Comment: You need to paste the code where `header` and `footer` components are loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `*ngIf` directive for your components... or place your `router-outlet` to the upper level and recognize page without header/footer.
it is not working

Comment: what do I use NgIf with which condition?  and I just write <router-outlet> on top of components?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove your `header` and `footer` from the root level and include them only in the pages where you need to show them.

Or you could define a service which you can use to decide wheather you will show the header and footer or not. You could you `ActivatedRoute` or `Router` inside the service for tracking the current page path.
And you can use `*ngIf` condition in your component having the header and footer.